# Windows Server Docker container cannot connect to proxy container after web server restart

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, network-programming, windows-server

I have 2 Windows Server Docker containers deployed with Docker Compose. One container runs a reverse proxy server and the other runs a web server. The web server serves a simple index.html page. Both are running Nginx.

When run, everything works as expected. I can access content via the proxy. But if I restart the web server I get a bad gateway error. I then need to restart the proxy to get it working again.

How do I get this working without the need to restart the proxy?

Docker-compose:

```yaml
version: '3'

services: 
    web:
        build:
            context: ./web
            dockerfile: ./dockerfile
    proxy:
        build:
            context: ./proxy
            dockerfile: ./dockerfile
        ports:
            - "8089:80"
```

Proxy Dockerfile:

```yaml
FROM sixeyed/nginx:windowsservercore

COPY nginx.conf C:/nginx/conf
CMD C:\nginx\nginx.exe
```

Proxy nginx.config:

```
events {
}
http {
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_pass http://web:80/;
        }
    }
}
```

Web Dockerfile:

```yaml
FROM sixeyed/nginx:windowsservercore

COPY nginx.conf C:/nginx/conf
COPY index.html C:/nginx/html/index.html

CMD C:\nginx\nginx.exe
```

Web nginx.config:

```
events {
}

http {
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Problem

`web` reference in the `proxy` container’s nginx.conf is referring to the up of the container that is referenced when nginx server was started. When `web` restarts the old ip becomes unavailable and a new ip is used, the container `web` reference is then updated, however nginx server is still referencing the old ip since configuration changes are only applied on start/restart.

## Solution

You need to restart the nginx proxy server—not necessarily the container—when your web container is replaced. This can be done by using docker-gen to monitor metadata regarding containers and restart nginx when a change is detected. Luckily nginx-proxy, does this for you. nginx-proxy is well maintained, and an alternative to you having to maintain this business logic yourself.

## References

Nginx Proxy: https://github.com/nginx-proxy/nginx-proxy

Comment: How do bigger companies get around this? I mean, once one of the servers is restarted, the entire server park needs to be restarted, that can't be the case right?

Comment: @Caramiriel larger companies would use something such as ECS or Kubernetes

Comment: For nginx, the nginx-proxy solution will work properly. But if I read the comment correctly, for containers connecting to each other it's recommended to use ECS or K8s? And the restart is not necessary with these libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Nginx is caching the resolved DNS IP of `web` container.
You can configure Nginx to invalidate DNS cache(use different TTL than the one set on DNS record) by adding `resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=1s` to the proxy nginx.config file.

Info on Nginx resolver: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver